# Combine two LINQ queries from different sources into single object

Tags: c#, linq

I am gathering data from two different sources with the intention of populating a single object.  My class is

```
public class SampleClient
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobUrl { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

The first LINQ query populates a collection of `SampleClient` objects obtaining values for all except Version.  I then need to loop through the collection of `SampleClient` and utilize `ClientId` value in the second query.  The result of the second query is the Version value.  Here is my first LINQ query:

```
    private void btnProjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] stringArray = { "demo", "sample", "test", "training" };
        List<SampleClient> jobList =
        (
            from x in XDocument.Load(XML URL VALUE HERE).Root.Elements("job")
            where x.Element("name").Value.Contains("-config") && x.Element("name").Value.StartsWith("oba-")
            && (!stringArray.Any(s => x.Element("name").Value.Contains(s)))
            select new SampleClient
            {
                ClientId = getClientId((string)x.Element("name")),
                JobName = (string)x.Element("name"),
                JobUrl = (string)x.Element("url"),
            }).ToList();

        foreach (SampleClient job in jobList)
        {
            //Display the results in a textbox
            txtResults.Text += "Job Name = " + job.JobName + " | Job URL = " + job.JobUrl + " | ";
        }
    }
```

In the query that obtains the version, I currently have:

```
var version = from item in doc.Descendants(ns + "properties")
select new SampleClient
{
    ClientId = strClientId,
    Version = (string)item.Element(ns + "product.version").Value
};
```

It is important to note that the URL source used in the second query is created using the `ClientId` that was obtained from the first.  I could have a routine loop through and cleanup / merge objects, but this feels like a hack.  Is there a cleaner way of handling this?

This is a sample of the XML from the first query:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allView>
    <description>PROD</description>
    <job>
        <name>abc</name>
        <url>http://ci-client.company.net/job/abc/</url>
        <color>blue</color>
    </job>
    <job>
        <name>acme</name>
        <url>http://ci-client.company.net/job/acme/</url>
        <color>blue</color>
    </job>
</allView>
```

The second query URL is dynamically created by using the clientID from the results of the first.  I am using this to load in a Maven POM file and grab version information.  Here is a snippet of the XML from the POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
    <groupId>com.company.xyz</groupId> 
    <artifactId>io</artifactId> 
    <version>6.11.7-ACME-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <packaging>pom</packaging> 
    <properties>
        <product.version>6.11.7</product.version> 
        <db.version>1.4</db.version> 
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>policies</module> 
        <module>templates</module> 
        <module>assemble</module> 
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: where does strClientId come from in the second query?

Comment: The intention (although not fully functional yet) is that it would come from looping through the results of the first query.  Said differently, it is ClientId from the collection of SampleClient created by the first query.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Show an example of your XML sources.

Comment: if you are passing strClinetId from the sampleClient already created, then just pass the object and put the version directly on the object.

Comment: though I don't understand the second query, from what you have said, you are implying you have one strClientId,  and the query implies many versions.....

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses.  I added the sample XML sources as requested by dtb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var jobList = from x in XDocument.Load(...
              where ...
              let clientId = getClientId((string)x.Element("name"))
              select new SampleClient
              {
                  ClientId = clientId,
                  JobName = (string)x.Element("name"),
                  JobUrl = (string)x.Element("url"),
                  Version = (string)XDocument
                      .Load(GetSecondQueryUrl(clientId))
                      .Root
                      .Element(pom4 + "properties")
                      .Element(pom4 + "product.version")
              };
```

Comment: Thanks dtb.  I will try in the morning.  Assuming this works, it is certainly cleaner than I was envisioning.  I really need to learn this LINQ stuff!

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand your question..

This will merge them together (although, my test data only had ClientId, JobName and Version..). Query 1 contains ClientId and JobName, Query2 contains ClientId and Version.

```
IList<SampleClient> mergedList = firstQuery.Concat(secondQuery)
    .ToLookup(x => x.ClientId)
    .Select(x => x.Aggregate((query1, query2) => 
            new SampleClient() { 
                    ClientId = query1.ClientId, 
                    JobName = query1.JobName,
                    Version = query2.Version 
                }
            )
    ).ToList();
```

..possibly not as efficient as your manual method.. however I have nothing to benchmark against..

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback.  I do think you understand my question and I will try this in the morning.  Since I am new to LINQ, I have to ask what may be a stupid question.  You reference firstQuery, secondQuery as well as query1 and query2.  Can you help me piece together where these are defined?  Thanks again.

Comment: `firstQuery` and `secondQuery` are just my placeholders for your two queries you mentioned in your question. I pre-populated my placeholders with dummy data. `query1` and `query2` are the individual items the aggregate uses to build the returned list.